# How to automate Audit after sql DB shutdown?

Tags: sql, oracle, audit

I have made this instruction on my DB:

```
AUDIT CREATE SESSION BY USER
```

But when I shut the DB down I have to write the script again.
How can I automate this such that it automatically runs when the DB is started?

Comment: The question sentence does not reflect the issue you have. It seems to involve "where do I put my scripted code so it runs automatically"... You might want to edit it for better reflection and clarity.

Comment: I need how to run a script that contains "AUDIT CREATE SESSION BY USER" when start up the db